# Is a mezuzah needed between an antechamber and the main rooms?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

If right when a person enters his front door, he enters a small "room" which is basically a place where people can take off their shoes before coming into the house proper, and this "room" is not 4x4 amos, and this "room" has a lintel and two doorposts as the entrance to the larger living room, would that doorpost that is the entrance to the larger living room require a mezuzah, and if so, would the front door to the house itself not require a mezuzah, since it leads directly into the "room" that is not 4x4 amos?

Comment: You can always ask any practical questions concerning mezuzot and tefillin to both R' Aaron Shaffer of [MezuzahStore.com](https://mezuzahstore.com/pages/contact-us) and R' Melech Michaels of [Mezuzah Depot](http://www.mezuzadepot.com/contact/). They are both true _erlicher yidden_ and will answer any questions you have.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what a Beit Shaar is? They should both be obligated

Comment: @ezra, R' Michaels actually has a blog post on site about just this very situation, and says that a mezuzah is required in this case.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - A link would be great, because that could serve as an answer in this case!

Answer (score 1):

I asked the Rabbi and he said that both need a mezuzah.  But why would the front door of the house require a mezuzah, since it says on note 27 in the Artscroll Kitzur Shulchan Aruch that according to Rabbi Moshe Feinstein in [Igros Moshe Yoreh Deah 1, 181](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=355&hilite=), a room that does not have the requisite size to require a mezuzah but which opens to a larger room, the smaller room is exempt?